# How to Share write access, SQLite database between 2 applications?

Tags: sqlite

Ohkay, so here is what I am trying to do.

I have a c program that connects to Google Chromes "Web Data" Sqlite db and it can read and write to it when chrome is not launched. But the minute Chrome is launched , i only have read access to the db.

Is there any way i can make my program perform writing operations onto the db while chrome is open?

like temporarily shut down chrome's access to the db for a few miliseconds to insert 1 row into the db and then let chrome take charge again?

Willing to put a bounty on this .. please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if google WebData has same implementation as sqlite even if it is same sql engine, but there is possibility to open same SQLite file and perform lock when you are trying to write and release lock when you finished writing, below is link to doc for SQLite.

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html - concurrency

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_handler.html - locking handler

I presume that the only problem you will have is, does google chrome ever release this lock :)

Comment: yes thats exactly my problem :( how do i find out if chrome releases the lock? or can i make it release the lock for sometime while I write to the db?

Comment: Try with sqlite3_busy_handler() or sqlite3_busy_timeout() http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html I think your app needs to wait for lock to be released. I don't know how you could force google chrome to release lock :) Anyway, I'm sure that chrome releases lock at some point. Even chrome has a lot concurrency to handle inside itself ;). I would say that sqlite3_busy_timeout() is your best chance